# Problema is not a function ao modificar uma posição num tile

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema que ao tentar atribuir uma nova posição a um player ele diz  is not a function. Como é que posso resolver isso para que o player a pareça numa nova casa.

```
class Player{
   constructor(id, img){
   this.id = id;
   this.tileID = 0;
}

getID(){
    return this.id;
}

setTileCount(diceResult) {
    this.tileID = this.tileID + diceResult;
}

getTileID() {
    return this.tileID;
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 class Tile {

  constructor(x, y, lar, alt, id, img) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.lar = lar;
    this.alt = alt;
    this.id = id;
    this.img = img;

this.centerPos = createVector(x, y);
this.players = [];
this.posPlayer1 = createVector(this.centerPos.x + 20, this.centerPos.y + 40);
this.posPlayer2 = createVector(this.centerPos.x + 50, this.centerPos.y + 40);
this.posPlayer3 = createVector(this.centerPos.x + 50, this.centerPos.y + 60);
this.posPlayer4 = createVector(this.centerPos.x + 20, this.centerPos.y + 60);
  }

  showTiles() {
    //noStroke();
    let q = color(223, 216, 216);
    fill(q);
    rect(this.centerPos.x, this.centerPos.y, this.lar, this.alt, this.id);
    image(this.img, this.centerPos.x, this.centerPos.y, this.lar, this.alt);

  }

showPlayer(){
  if(this.players.length != 0){
for (var i = 0; i<this.players.length; i++){
  if(this.players[i].getID() == 1 && this.id == this.players[i].getTileID()){
    circle(this.posPlayer1.x, this.posPlayer1.y, 10);
  } else if(this.players[i].getID() == 2 && this.id == this.players[i].getTileID()){
    circle(this.posPlayer2.x, this.posPlayer2.y, 10);
  } else if(this.players[i].getID() == 3 && this.id == this.players[i].getTileID()){
    circle(this.posPlayer3.x, this.posPlayer3.y, 10);
} else if(this.players[i].getID() == 4 && this.id == this.players[i].getTileID()){
    circle(this.posPlayer4.x, this.posPlayer4.y, 10);
  }
 }
}
}

startGame() {
  this.players.push(pl1);
  this.players.push(pl2);
  this.players.push(pl3);
  this.players.push(pl4);
}

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

O problema encontra-se nesta função do draw.

```
function draw() {
 for (var i=0; i<tileRowDown.length;i++){
  tileRowDown[i].showPlayer();
 }

 pl1.setTileCount(2); //is not a function
  pl1.showPlayer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setTileCount [não foi declarada dentro da classe Player](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Corpo_de_uma_classe_e_defini%C3%A7%C3%B5es_de_m%C3%A9todos), logo, setTileCount não é um método de Player.

Digo isso imaginado pl1 seja uma instância da classe Player.